# Can't edit build process template in VS2017

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, build-definition

Whenever I edit a build definition for a solution and go to the "Process" tab I get the following error:

> Team Foundation Error
>
> Type
>   'Microsoft.VisuaStudio.Services.Integration.VssAadVSAccountProviderCredential'
>   in assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Integration,
>   Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
>   not marked as serializable.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.2 (26430.16) Release.

Any thoughts?

*Note: it works on VS2012

Comment: do you have a git project configured?

Comment: @Juanito yes I do, but I can't get why this is related.

Comment: How did you edit the build process in VS2017? Did you use any related plugin?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT just right click "Edit build"

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I am also encoutering the same issue

Comment: No, I couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to the credentials in VSTS, try to do the following:

**Reset your credentials**

- Go to Control Panel > User Accounts > Manage Windows Credentials > In tab Generic Credentials, find the one for your TFS server and edit the credentials.
- If that doesn’t work, try removing the credential.

This is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25802014/3806089)

Comment: But I am using VSTS not TFS